# ion-slides with smooth scrolling and no snapping

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, slider, ion-slides

I'd like to use the `<ion-slides>` component to create a album thumbnail scroller like on the Spotify mobile app. I have mostly got it working but I want to be able to disable the snapping. Is this possible?

```
<ion-slides centeredSlides="false" slidesPerView="2.5" spaceBetween="-16">
  <ion-slide padding *ngFor="let album of albums">
    <ion-card>
      <img [src]="album.image">
      <ion-item>
        <h3 ion-text text-center>{{ album.title }}</h3>
        <p ion-text text-center>{{ album.artist }}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

I thought there might just be an input setting for the component that disables the snapping but I cannot find anything like this in the docs.

Comment: You allready found something?

Comment: @juliusbangert have you perhaps solved this? I am trying to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed by [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com) in your slider options add the following. See example here https://swiperjs.com/demos/150-freemode.html

```
freeMode: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem today, and have come across the following article that seems to do what we re trying:

[Ionic 4 | Multiple Slides on Single View Using Swiper Slider](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-multiple-slides-on-single-view-using-swiper-slider/#more-1410)

I have yet to get it working, but will keep you updated if I do. Thought it might help you in the meantime.